# Web Service Form GUI

Tags: web-services, user-interface, wsdl, xforms

Due to a delay in a UI deliverable, the company I am at is suggesting a tactical workaround to give users direct access to web service endpoints via SOAP UI so that they can manually invoke an endpoint.

There surely must be a better alternative out there.  It needs to:

1) Be super quick to design and deploy - no code solution.  The WSDL already contains everything that the form needs to submit, so it should be able to be auto-generated. 
2) Needs to support the full XSD, not like the original .net web helper page that gave up on complex types.
3) When it posts the data to the service it needs to be robust, either fail with obvious errors, or succeed with a message.
4) Can be a server side or client side solution (but not cloud).  Ideally something that I can just download and run.  I do not want to have to engage a vendor.
5) Free or cheap.
6) Optional - ability to tweak the form.

I was thinking of some sort of XForm solution, as you can easily post to a service using XForms.  I have looked for a few options but came up surprisingly short.

Any ideas?  This should already exist!

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two problems to solve here:

1. Generate the XForms from WSDL
   Although it's technically possible, no open source or comercial development exists.
   If you like to be the first, maybe this could help you: http://portal.visiontecnologica.com/xforms/

This is an XForms generator from XML instances. You are welcome to use and adapt it for WSDL and to add the validations to submissions required to validate the responses from webservices.

2. Validating against XSD
   In an ideal world, this task should be acomplished by web services, not by the UI in order keep data integrity.
   XForms adds Little support for XSD validation, generally this is a server side task, but you could use a Javscript library like XML.js to do the XSD validatiion before submitting the XForms instance.

An XML/XForms expert could build something to solve your problem in a couple of weeks, but this kinds of geeks are hard to find. Let suggest somebody that could help you: http://collinta.com.au